# Is there a way to query all the _mappings in Elasticsearch for a common element?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm looking for a way to query across all the different mappings in my Elasticsearch instance to find which mappings reference each other.
e.g. I have mappings for events, vehicles, and businesses which all have a Person Name element as a referential pointer.
I'd like to query all the _mappings in one shot that might also have this element.

While I understand that I can query each _mapping and in a reasonable period of time, determine if one element is common between each different mapping, it would be better for me to send a single query and get an aggregate of the different mappings which reference a given element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `get field mapping` API:

```
GET /_all/_mapping/field/timestamp
```

Which results with all `timestamp` fields mapped in all indices (indexes):

```
{
  ".monitoring-kibana-6-2019.06.12" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "doc" : {
        "timestamp" : {
          "full_name" : "timestamp",
          "mapping" : {
            "timestamp" : {
              "type" : "date",
              "format" : "date_time"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  ".monitoring-es-6-2019.06.12" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "doc" : {
        "timestamp" : {
          "full_name" : "timestamp",
          "mapping" : {
            "timestamp" : {
              "type" : "date",
              "format" : "date_time"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "app_events_201901" : {
    "mappings" : { }
  },
  "app_events_201902" : {
    "mappings" : { }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  That was so simple that I'm almost embarrassed to have asked.  It was exactly what I needed.